# How to save to local storage using Ngrx?

Tags: angular, local-storage, ngrx, state-management

I am trying to save a simple menu state whether it is 'open' or 'close' to the browser localStorage. I know I can do it by using `localStorage.setItem`. But, my project is using NGRX. Is there a better way to deal this using NGRX? By default, the menu is open. If I close it and close the browser and return back, it should be closed.

Is there a way to do it using NGRX or localStorage is the better solution? I am just learning NGRX. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Mind sharing what you got so far? Preferably a demo of sorts like a stackblitz

Comment: You could use https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function that you set in your initial state that could pull data from local storage

```
StoreModule.forRoot(
    { someReducer: reducer },
    { initialState: getInitialAppState }
  ),
```

then in the function you could do something like this

```
export function getInitialAppState() {
    const previousSettings  = localStorage.getItem("settings")
    if (previousSettings  != null) {
         return JSON.parse(previousSettings);
    }
    return {};
}
```

So if you stored some settings at one point in a previous setting it will set that as an inistal state. to store these settings you can have a selector in your app.component or somewhere more fitting listing to settings and just JSON.stringify that state you want to store.

Comment: 1. you might want to use a meta-reducer (see https://ngrx.io/guide/store/metareducers),  a function called each time before normal reducers, allows save the state all the time. 2. hydrate your state on app start 3. There are solutions for 1+2. see www.npmjs.com/package/ngrx-store-localstorage.  4. consider using indexDB over localstorage. 5. check out Capacitor/Persistance (https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/preferences). In-browser, it uses indexdb.  on mobile - native platform means. 6. github.com/whjvenyl/ngrx-store-capacitor = 1+2+4+5

Comment: 1. no only need to do it on initialization 2. is what it does 3. why install packages for something that only requires 3 lines of code ? 4. could use indexDB, but i prefer to keep things simple.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure what is the best.
But for me NGRX is kind of big thing and it might need so many setting/initializing code.
When I'm doing simple task or feature I don't use NGRX, I think many tasks and requirements can be handled by localStorage, Service, Observable.
However, it's ok if you want to learn NGRX

Comment: The question was not whether use ngrx. The question was "how to, with ngrx".